# How can I set a Id to my textbox in Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, automation, appium

I want to set a Identifier to my text boxes and buttons, because I want to automate my app using Appium.

So my question is, in Xcode, what can I do to set a Id for my options, Its possible to do that, because all the programs that I have inspect has a id.

Comment: I guess you can use `UIView.tag` for that. It is an integer that can be set from both Interface Builder and code

Answer (score 9):

You just need to give it an accessibility identifier.

You can add this as a user defined runtime attribute, do it in code or the easiest is to add it through the property inspector.

**Code**

```
titleLabel.accessibilityIdentifier = "titleLabel"
```

**Property Inspector**

[image]